# $state.go('XXX') doesn't work in angularJS project

Tags: angularjs

1. Conditions: AngularJS V1.0.3, Angular-UI-Router V0.2.10
2. What I want to implement is the index html page will dynamically forward to login html, then click login button, it will re-forward to home page.
3. Due to my reputation is not enough so I can not attach the images. Here I will attach my demo code.
   3.1: index.html

   ```
           <!-- StateProvider -->
           <div ng-controller="demoController">
               <button ng-click="goToHomePage()">Go To Home Page</button>
           </div>

           <!-- Load extra js -->
           <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
           <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
           <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
           <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
           <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular/angular-animate.js"></script>
           <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/angular-ui/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

           <script type="text/javascript" src="js/appDemo.js"></script>
           <script type="text/javascript" src="js/service/DemoService.js"></script>
           <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller/DemoController.js"></script>

       </body>
   ```

   3.2: appDemo.js

   ```
   var app = angular.module("demo", ['ui.router']);

   app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

   //$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/landing/dashboard");
   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");
   //$urlRouterProvider.when('/landing/influencers', '/landing/influencers/dashboard/market-view');

   $stateProvider
       .state('home', {
           url: '/home',
           templateUrl: 'view/home.html',
           controller: function(){
               alert("123");
           }
       })

       .state('login', {
           url: '/login',
           templateUrl: 'view/login.html'
       });
   }]);

   app.run(['$state', function ($state) {
       alert("running...");
       /*$state.transitionTo('home');*/
       $state.go('home');
   }]);
   ```

   3.3: DemoController.js

   ```
   app.controller('demoController', function($scope, $state, demoService){

       $scope.goToHomePage = function(){
           alert('AAA');
           $state.go("home");
       }

   });
   ```

   When I click the 'Go To Home Page' button, nothing happened but prompted a message 'AAA' which setted in goToHomePage  function.

   Any idea how to forward to home page correctly?

   Any suggestion should be highly appreciated.

Comment: you are using too old version of angular update it to `angular-1.3.15` & see what happen

Comment: @pankajparkar, I updated the angular version to 1.3.9, and it's working perfectly, thank you very much.

Comment: check i've added an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have too old version `angularjs` which is not compatible with `angular-ui-roter`.

Updating angular script version from `1.0.3` to `1.3.15` will solve you issue.